# fetch value from json Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am getting below response from server after using **Dropzone.js** plugin , i need to fetch "thumbnail_url" but not able to do it .it is array containg json object .

> "[{"name": "Lighthouse.jpg", "url":
>   "/your_uploads/multiuploader_file/8d1c455f5c49a9cfec8a3e880ff4d6904e2ce4a2/",
>   "id": "8d1c455f5c49a9cfec8a3e880ff4d6904e2ce4a2", "thumbnail_url":
>   "thumbnails/Lighthouse.8d1c455f5c49a9cfec8a3e880ff4d6904e2ce4a2.jpg",
>   "delete_type": "POST", "delete_url":
>   "/your_uploads/multiuploader_delete/8d1c455f5c49a9cfec8a3e880ff4d6904e2ce4a2/",
>   "size": 561276}]"

I tried doing it many way but nothing worked, i tried below it works but i cant change server code so help me to fetch from above json Array  .

```
var obj={"name": "Lighthouse.jpg", "url": "/your_uploads/multiuploader_file/8d1c455f5c49a9cfec8a3e880ff4d6904e2ce4a2/", "id": "8d1c455f5c49a9cfec8a3e880ff4d6904e2ce4a2", "thumbnail_url": "thumbnails/Lighthouse.8d1c455f5c49a9cfec8a3e880ff4d6904e2ce4a2.jpg", "delete_type": "POST", "delete_url": "/your_uploads/multiuploader_delete/8d1c455f5c49a9cfec8a3e880ff4d6904e2ce4a2/", "size": 561276};

>>> obj.name
"Lighthouse.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON in array of objects. In order to access first object keys use `jso[0].thumbnail_url`

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var jso = [{
                "name": "Lighthouse.jpg",
                    "url": "/your_uploads/multiuploader_file/8d1c455f5c49a9cfec8a3e880ff4d6904e2ce4a2/",
                    "id": "8d1c455f5c49a9cfec8a3e880ff4d6904e2ce4a2",
                    "thumbnail_url": "thumbnails/Lighthouse.8d1c455f5c49a9cfec8a3e880ff4d6904e2ce4a2.jpg",
                    "delete_type": "POST",
                    "delete_url": "/your_uploads/multiuploader_delete/8d1c455f5c49a9cfec8a3e880ff4d6904e2ce4a2/",
                    "size": 561276
            }]

            alert(jso[0].thumbnail_url)
        });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8wKxY/7/)

Answer (score 0):

try the below solution

```
   alert(obj[0].name);
   alert(obj[0].thumbnail_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well try this in your success method:

```
$.each(data, function(i, item){
   console.log(item.thumbnail_url);
});
```